# What are the memory limitations of regex matching in python? (looking for repetition in large file)

Tags: python, regex, memory

I am searching for repeated data (of any length) in a binary file (happens to be an audio recording, read with `wave` module)

This is the expression I'm using:

`r = re.compile(r"((..){4,})\1")`

...because the audio samples are 2 bytes each and the results should be at minimum 8 bytes.

and then to remove the duplicated regions:

```
for match in r.finditer(buffer):
    buffer = buffer.replace( match.group(0), match.group(1) )
```

I realize I'm asking a lot -- the repeated data could be anywhere in the file  and it could be any length. In fact the algorithm only works when the repeated regions are small (<800 bytes) and it is more successful if the repeated data is  closer to the beginning of the data stream. Otherwise, it just returns 0 results.

Is there a way to expand the resources available to the regex matching? Or to predict the usage necessary to maybe reduce the problem size into more manageable pieces?

Comment: I'm assuming you only want to remove repeated sections that occur next to each other?  What about data that is repeated multiple times in a row?  Would you be doing multiple passes (removing one duplicate may cause a section to match earlier data, so you'd have to check the file after the first replace)?

Comment: @BrendanAbel it would be adjacent repetitions only, and only the first occurrence in the file, given the nature of the data

Comment: First occurence is still ambiguous.  For example, `121234121234`.  The first occurrence is `1212` (duplicated `12`).  But if you read the whole string, you can find a longer duplicated section - `121234`

Comment: The regex above is greedy and returns the largest string possible. Also it's adjacent repetitions only so 121234 is the only answer in your example.

Comment: I'm not sure that a script language is well fitted for this kind of task. I think that a compiled language with a basic algorithm (without the use of a regex engine) is better for this task (IMO ada is the best).

Comment: Are you prioritizing on position or length of duplicate (in cases of multiple duplicates). For example `aacdecde`.  `aa` is technically the first duplicate, but there is a longer duplicate at the end `cdecde`?

Comment: As an aside, do not imagine that this kind of task takes a little time.

Comment: What is the goal of your request? (in a more general meaning)

Comment: @BrendanAbel no priority, both duplicates need to go

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have an hour of audio full of glitches. These glitches are little doubled chunks of audio, very short like .5 seconds. They occur randomly and very frequently through the audio file. They all need to be edited out.